# How to auto checked to one of many shipping free choose state when checkout in WooCommerce?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checked

I have a problem making this website.

There are the products to buy: http://tn.freshbrand.vn/danh-muc/than-khu-mui

And the checkout: http://tn.freshbrand.vn/checkout

When user buy more than 2 products and choose "Ngoài HCm" as the state where to ship:
The shipping fee shows 2 possible radio buttons to check. 
option1 : 45,000 (for 1 product)
option2 : 65,000 (not for 1 product).

When user choose state (Chọn Quận, huyện) == "Ngoài HCm".
and the cart has 1 product, the shipping fee should be auto checked to 45,000 (default).
and for more than 1 products in cart, it should be auto checked to 65,000.

Before, I had option 65,000 checked when the cart has more than 2 product but this was not ok. I think the jQuery must set when state (delivery destination) is chosen.

Below is my code in form-billing.php

```
global $woocommerce;
  $attendee_count = 0;
  if (sizeof($woocommerce->cart->get_cart())>0) :
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $item_id => $values) :
      $_product = $values['data'];
      if ($_product->exists() && $values['quantity']>0) :
        if (get_post_meta($_product->id, '_tribe_wooticket_for_event') > 0)
          $attendee_count += $values['quantity'];
      endif;
    endforeach;
  endif; 
  echo "<div class='sl_sp'>Number product in cart: <span class='soluong_sp'>" . $attendee_count . "</span></div>";
  if($attendee_count == 1 ){ // so luong la 1 sp
    ?>
    <style>
    .woocommerce ul#shipping_method li:nth-child(2)
    {display: none;}
    </style>
    <?
  }else{ ?>

  <style>
    .woocommerce ul#shipping_method li:nth-child(2){display: block;}
    .woocommerce ul#shipping_method li:nth-child(1){display: none;}
  </style>
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("input#shipping_method_0_oik_weight_zone_shipping_45").prop( "checked", true );
  });
  </script>

<?php }  ?>
```

I was set default state to 'Ngoài HCM', it's show correctly when I add 1 or more products. But when chosen another state, and choose 'Ngoài HCm' again, it's wrong (not checked correctly).

Comment: I edited your question a lot... Please re-read it to see if I did it correctly! ;)

Comment: Thankyou @LouysPatriceBessette . ^^

Comment: Try to only remove `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` and `});`(two lines below) But leave `jQuery("input#shipping_method_0_oik_weight_zone_shipping_45").prop( "checked", true );` because it is correct.

Comment: In short, just remove the "ready" wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is correct:

```
jQuery("input#shipping_method_0_oik_weight_zone_shipping_45").prop( "checked", true );
```

I tryed it in the console of your checkout page and it is working.
Now, since this code is injected in the page using Ajax, you don't need the "ready" function wrapper.

The page is already ready.
The `load` event will not occur.

So in clear, try just this:

```
<script>
  jQuery("input#shipping_method_0_oik_weight_zone_shipping_45").prop( "checked", true );
</script>
```

Instead of this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input#shipping_method_0_oik_weight_zone_shipping_45").prop( "checked", true );
});
</script>
```

Comment: add code in console it's successful, but when add code to file.php

/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-billing.php it's not working.

i was alert test case buy 1 product and > 1 products, it right alert ...

Comment: mmm.. We should have to dicuss slowly.. By defining everything step by step. *« was alert test case»* just fuzzed me. And, well... Could you please check my profile and get me on facebook ? --- **OR ANYONE COULD MAYBE upvote him** so he could have at least 20 rep. to access SO chat ??? ---

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette : Thanksyou for your support, 
i'm newbie on Wordpress and woocommerce. 

my problem was solved by move all code to shiping method file.
/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-shiping.php. 

and jquery run Oke. 

i can't find your facebook in profile, can you give me a link to make friends and discuss some thing about wordpress, php ...etc...
thanks for your support again...

Comment: i will update my result tonight for every body can view and use it. <br/>